# Firebase expire verification code in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase PhoneAuthProvider to login user by phone number verification. I want to expire the verification code sent after some time like 30 seconds. Is it possible to expire the code? If so how can I do that.

Comment: seconds is pretty tight for text message authentication, since it is not guaranteed to be delivered in 30 seconds. If you need such short authentication window maybe it would be better to use some other method.

Comment: 30 seconds is unreasonably short as `Andras M` mentioned. That said, you can't change the expiration time of an SMS code with Firebase phone authentication.

Comment: @AndrasM. 30 seconds is just an example. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to expire a code after some time.

Comment: @bojeil thanks for the input